# why is the code returning IndexError error in python when the synsets of the word exists

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, wordnet

I do not understand why I am getting this error. Please help

```
>>> mylist = []
>>> file1 = open("medDict.txt", "r")
>>> for line in file1:
    from nltk.corpus import wordnet
    print line
    wordFromList2 = wordnet.synsets(line)[0]
    mylist.append(wordFromList2)


abnormal


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 4, in <module>
    wordFromList2 = wordnet.synsets(line)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

medDict.txt contains the below words

```
abnormal
acne
ache
diarrhea
fever
```

Comment: You should usually import everything at the top of the script, per PEP 8: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

Answer (score 1):

@Blender was right about whitespace sensitivity for `word.synsets()`. If you need to access any `synsets` that have **whitespace** in natural language, Wordnet uses the **underscore** `_` instead of . E.g. if you want to find something like `kick the bucket` you access the synsets from the NLTK WN interface with `wn.synsets("kick_the_bucket")`

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> wn.synsets('kick the bucket')
[]
>>> wn.synsets('kick_the_bucket')
[Synset('die.v.01')]
```

However, do note that sometimes WordNet has encoded some synset with dashes instead of underscore. E.g. `9-11` is accessible but `9_11` isn't.

```
>>> wn.synsets('9-11')
[Synset('9/11.n.01')]
>>> wn.synsets('9_11')
[]
```

Now to resolve your problems with your code.

**1.** When you read a file line by line, you also read the invisible but existing `\n` in the line. So you need to change this:

```
>>> mylist = []
>>> file1 = open("medDict.txt", "r")
```

to this:

```
>>> words_from_file = [i.strip() for i in open("medDict.txt", "r")]
```

**2.** I'm not very sure you really want `wordnet.synsets(word)[0]`, this means you only take the first sense, do note that it might not be the `Most Frequent Sense (MFS)`. So instead of doing this:

```
>>> wordFromList2 = wordnet.synsets(line)[0]
>>> mylist.append(wordFromList2)
```

I think the more appropriate way is to use a `set` instead and then `update` the set

```
>>> list_of_synsets = set()
>>> for i in words_from_file:
>>>  list_of_synsets.update(wordnet.synsets(i))
>>> print list_of_synsets
```

Answer (score 0):

`word.synsets()` is whitespace-sensitive:

```
>>> wordnet.synsets('abnormal')
    [Synset('abnormal.a.01'), Synset('abnormal.a.02'), Synset('abnormal.s.03')]
>>> wordnet.synsets(' abnormal')
    []
```

`.strip()` the whitespace from your line before passing it in:

```
wordFromList2 = wordnet.synsets(line.strip())[0]
```